# why isPresent() is not working as expected?

Tags: protractor, cucumber, bdd, assert, chai

I want to check that under certain circumstances, a dropdown is not present in the DOM. 
In order to do this, I have created this feature:

```
Scenario Outline: Flexibility Use Case. US31032. When I select the Product Line, 
                  Program it will be blanked/greyed out. (Program="NULL")

    Given I am on the application
    Then application is running
    When <productLine> has value <productLineValue>
    Then <dropdown> not clickable
    And content of the template is not empty

Examples:
  |productLine       |productLineValue  | dropdown  |
  |templateSelection |AT_CURTAIL        | whatever  |
```

The problem is that it does not matter if the dropdown exists or not, the expect always pass the expect sentence.
See code below:

```
Then(/^(.*) not clickable$/, function (dropdown,callback) {
    HomePage.DropdownGreyedOut(dropdown); 
    callback();
});

 DropdownGreyedOut: function (dropdown)
{
    let el =element(by.id(''+dropdown+''));
    expect(el.isPresent()).to.eventually.be.equal(false);
}
```

Any idea about what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its possible that an element is hidden while still being present. Try `.isDisplayed()`

Comment: Same problem @BenMohorc. Indeed, I am writing an id that does not exist for sure. Thanks.

Comment: Show the HTML code when `productLine=templateSelection`